# How to change default idle for python?

Tags: python, python3, python-2.7, idle, idle-python

Okay, so I have python 3.5 on my system. Whenever I open a `.py` file, Idle3 starts, thus pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> will instantly run my code.

However I need python 2.7 now for an assignment. In terminal I've installed 'idle' so, I can open idle and idle3 there easily.

My problem is, I can't change my `.py` files' default application to idle. It only sees idle3, so I can't open my files with idle(2.7) as default.

Is there any simple workaround for that?

Comment: Try this but in reverse http://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3#321000

Comment: i suggest this you use alias or just run `idle file.py` in the terminal..

Comment: typing `python --version` into terminal I get: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory`, but  `python2 --version` and  `python3 --version` works fine.