# How to restore after accidentally apt-get remove python

Tags: 16.04, apt, python

Yeah, I did this, it was stupid.

I did not know it will pull its dependencies with it, I just wanted to install python 2 and 3 from scratch (because of this problem: [How to change default idle for python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897355/how-to-change-default-idle-for-python)).

Now, I still can use my terminal, checked these answers:

[Apt-get remove python ~150Mb / apt-get install python 687kb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741265/apt-get-remove-python-150mb-apt-get-install-python-687kb)

[I accidentaly did sudo apt-get remove python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437644/i-accidentaly-did-sudo-apt-get-remove-python)

However after running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` I get these errors:

```
Setting up python-ldb (2:1.1.24-1ubuntu3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-ldb.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-ldb.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-ldb (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-tdb (1.3.8-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tdb.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tdb.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-tdb (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-samba:
 python-samba depends on python-crypto; however:
  Package python-crypto is not configured yet.
 python-samba depends on python-ldb (>= 1.1.2~); however:
  Package python-ldb is not configured yet.
 python-samba depends on python-tdb; however:
  Package python-tdb is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 mercurial-common
 python-crypto
 python-dnspython
 python-ldb
 python-tdb
 python-samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is the way to restore these dependencies (16.04 LTS)?

Comment: Aren't there specific errors listed earlier in the output? Will you please try to post them? Thanks!

Comment: Yepp, there is sorry. Edited question.

Comment: Try to install the package `python-minimal` first. It's the one containing `pycompile`.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch
Nope, throws the same problem :(

Comment: First, try running: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -f install` and if that doesn't resolve things, try running: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  Please post any errors, thanks!

Comment: Tried this as well, did not work, but posted a solution which has fixed it at last. Thank you anyway, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Managed to get it done this afternoon.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python python-chardet python-colorama python-distlib python-django python-django-tables2 python-six python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-urllib3 python-requests python-pip python-virtualenv

sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dnspython

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install
```

After a whole day of adventures in the deepest pits of the internet, these commands worked for me.

python-dnspython and samba was still missing after the first command, `--reinstall python-dnspython` pulled samba in as well. Autoremove removed the needless dependencies.

Comment: The crucial part was likely the reinstallation of `python-minimal`. In a single short command that's `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall python-minimal`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that separately before, but did not work on its own, so you may use the first then autoremove to be sure.  Still, you are right, it must be included.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-all # for python3
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to fix at least one version of python back to working condition before I tried your line.