# How to set python 3 as default interpreter while working with rPython

Tags: 16.04, python, r

I have Anaconda installed in my system with Python 3.5. 
When I run:

```
$ which python
```

in the terminal, it correctly shows the intended one i.e. the one within Anaconda. When typed:

```
$ python --version
```

it shows Python 3.5.3. Now when I installed the rPython package in R, it is taking the python from `usr/bin/python` which is Python 2.7.12.

How to set the correct python interpreter for R using rPython?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)

Comment: @adadion: I don't think that will help because that question doesn't deal with how to tell rPython about a different Python interpreter. See my answer.

Comment: great, even that will works too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [rPython `INSTALL` manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/INSTALL):

> In systems where several Python versions coexist, the user can choose the Python version to use at installation time. By default, the package will be installed using the Python version given by
>
> ```
> $ python --version
> ```
>
> but it is possible to select a different one if the `PYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION` environment variable is appropriately set.
>
> For instance, if it is defined as
>
> ```
> RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3.2
> ```
>
> it will try to use Python 3.2 (looking for `python3.2` and `python3.2-config` in the path). If set to
>
> ```
> RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3
> ```
>
> it will install against the "canonical" Python version in the system within the 3.x branch.

Ergo, you need to start R with the environment variable `RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION` set to `3`, e. g.:

```
RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=3 R
```

The same applies if you're using R with some front-end.