# bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, python

Using Ubuntu 16.04, I have a problem with python3

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

$ sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer 
required:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-53 linux-headers-4.8.0-53-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-53-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-53-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

$ python3
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3

Comment: `python` calls python2 , to call python 3 use `python3`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `type python3` and `readlink -f /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Probably a broken system link `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3` or similar locate your python 3 binary and link it.

Comment: so now i'm with new problem, i started python and trying to execute file i got: </br> Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roaa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/roaa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/roaa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/roaa/.local/lib/python

Comment: @RoaaSolh if you have another terminal emulator that doesn't depend on python3 (e.g. `xterm`) you can start that from the launcher - alternatively, log in to a CLI virtual terminal via Ctrl-Alt-F1 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6

Comment: @steeldriver i solve the problem with python and terminal is working fine ,but new problem appears when trying to execute file .py that imports numpy

Comment: @RoaaSolh if you have a new problem, start a new question

Comment: no man this is not duplicate as how you can do alisasing as none of the python version are working....