# Could alias python=python3 in my bashrc cause problems?

Tags: command-line, python, gnome-terminal, python3, bashrc

I would like to use python3 as my default python when working with the terminal. If I added the line `alias python=python3` in my ~/.bashrc, could that cause problems with other programs?

Comment: No it should not. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3  Do note this comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3#comment407721_320996

Comment: Better to just use python3 in all your commands. And in your python programs you must use python3. `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as first line.