# Terminal not working after deleting python

Tags: gnome-terminal

Earlier, my default Python version was `python2.7`.

To upgrade it, I deleted `python` from `/usr/bin/` and renamed `python3.6` as `python` in the same directory.

Afterwards, my terminal stopped working.

It gets no response on opening it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Which version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you delete /usr/bin/python and how did you rename /usr/bin/python3.6 as  /usr/bin/python?

Comment: DO NOT rename `python3.6` as `python`. Doing so will break your system quite horribly. Depending upon the version of Ubuntu you are using, it might be recoverable, it might not.

Comment: ubuntu version-18.10, I deleted by going in the desired directory and simply by using the command rm command and rename it by mv python3.6 python

Comment: Short Story: **Python is integral to the system DO NOT remove Python nor edit the binaries, because Python and Python 3 operate differently, and are 'different software'**

Answer (score 4):

The main lesson here is not to mess with system files unless you know exactly what you're doing. The directory /usr/bin is managed by the package manager, APT (as in `apt-get` and `apt`), so you will never need to manually make changes to it. You're not alone though. Lots of folks make changes to the system Python setup without realizing that most of the GUI depends on it.

Now, how can you fix this?

1. Access a TTY. See [What is a tty, and how do I access a tty?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66195/301745)

   - If that doesn't work, boot into recovery mode. See [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/150367/301745)
2. Put `python3.6` back, cause the system depends on it (via `/usr/bin/python3`, which is a symlink to `python3.6`)

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6
   ```
3. Either reinstall `python2.7`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7-minimal
   ```

   or remove it (**warning** OP is using Ubuntu 18.10, which does not rely on `python-2.7` by default. If you're using a different version, don't do this)

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove python2.7
   ```
4. Either figure out another way to set Python 3 as the default (see [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/q/320996/301745)), or learn to live with typing `python3` every time.