# python installed in ubuntu but python command not found

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, python

I have installed python 2.7  and python 3.7 in my ubuntu 18.04 but when i

type python it shows

```
  Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

  sudo apt install python3       
  sudo apt install python        
  sudo apt install python-minimal

  You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.
```

but i already installed python.

Comment: You said you installed both `python` & `python3` ?  when they were both already installed (ie. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS comes with both though 3.6 for python3). How did you install them?  and did you remove or replace the pre-installed versions?   I suspect your issue is $PATH, that you removed the preinstalled versions that were in your path, installed it elsewhere or amended your $PATH to something different to default.

Comment: i installed python 3.7

Comment: I asked HOW you installed them. If you used commands; `history` can refresh your memory on how.  On my Lubuntu a `whereis python` tells me where it is, and the command `echo $PATH` shows the list of directories searched for commands. What I suggested may be corrupted on yours, or if you installed from source (why I asked HOW) it could be installed outside of $PATH defaults.  If I enter `python --version` mine responds 2.7.16, and `python3 --version` responds 3.7.3 (note: I'm not using 18.04 so it's likely later versions). Did you remove anything? and how was it installed?

Comment: While people have pointed to various ways to make `python` invoke Python 3, is there a particular reason you can't just run `python3`?  If there is, it might be worth explaining what that reason is.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you could create an alias as follows:

```
alias python='python3'
```

by adding it to the `~/.bashrc` file at the end of this file, exiting and reloading it in the current terminal using the next command: `. ~/.bashrc`

Or using linking:

As you can see below, my `python` points to `python2`, `python2` points to `python2.7`.

To achieve the same, use:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

If you want `python` pointing to 3rd version, you could use the same, but the last command should be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

**Example**

```
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
user@lenovo:~$ ls -ailh /usr/bin/python*
1446954 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 жов 10 14:32 /usr/bin/python -> python2
1446952 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 жов 10 14:32 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
1465834 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3,6M лис  7 12:07 /usr/bin/python2.7
1447155 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 лис  7 12:07 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
1447156 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 жов 10 14:32 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
1442842 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 лют 12 00:23 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.7
1449245 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,9M лис 20 11:21 /usr/bin/python3.7
1447339 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 лис 20 11:21 /usr/bin/python3.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config
1449245 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,9M лис 20 11:21 /usr/bin/python3.7m
1447340 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 лис 20 11:21 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
1447341 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 жов  2 15:31 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.7-config
1442843 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  384 січ 30  2019 /usr/bin/python3-futurize
1442847 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 лют 12 00:23 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.7m
1447342 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 жов  2 15:31 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.7m-config
1442844 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  388 січ 30  2019 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
1447157 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 жов 10 14:32 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2-config
1455649 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   58 лип 10  2019 /usr/bin/pythontex -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py
1450999 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  306 лип 10  2019 /usr/bin/pythontex3
```

For managing python3 versions, you can use python alternatives to create symbolic links:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.11 2
```

And choose which one to use as using the command:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

For managing python2 and python3 using update-alternatives, you could see in michael's answer.

Comment: It's not a good idea to make direct changes to `/usr/bin/` under the feet of the operating system.  Doing so may cause problems on future upgrades.  Better approaches would be installing `python-is-python3` (only on 20.04 or newer), using a per-user `alias python=python3`, or simply running `python3` directly.

Comment: The packaging system assumes that it owns `/usr/bin/` (and `/usr/` in general outside of `/usr/local/`) and that users do not write there directly.  Arbitrary things may go wrong if you violate this rule, even if it seems relatively harmless.

Comment: It's not at all clear whether that's true.  The OP said they installed Python 2.7 and 3.7, but Ubuntu 18.04 comes with 2.7 and 3.6, so they must be doing something odd.  It's possible they have Python installed in some non-standard way rather than via the packaging system, so maybe they don't actually have the `python` package installed.

Comment: @ColinWatson is right, it's safer to use an alias rather than a symlink because other system-wide package dependencies may still require python2. More [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)

Comment: thanks that worked. Just need to relaunch terminal after adding alias, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 45):

This solution only applies to Ubuntu 20.04 (but sometimes people look at "similar issues" for a solution).

In the case you like `python` to refer to `python3`, you can simply install `python-is-python3`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

After this, invoking `python` will work just fine.

Comment: This is good advice for 20.04, but the OP asked about 18.04, where `python-is-python3` doesn't exist and where the rest of the OS is not prepared for `/usr/bin/python` being Python 3 and may fail unpredictably if that's forced.

Comment: Gosh, thanks Colin, I didn't check the package existance in 18.x sorry, I have modified the answer by specifing that applies only to 20.x, sometimes this is useful cause SO users fall here looking to similar issues. But if you think that it is better... I'll remove the answer.

Comment: Seems reasonable to just carefully qualify it as you've done.  Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between installing `python-is-python3` and just running `alias python='python3'`? I assume `python-is-python3` just runs that alias command.

Comment: ..or a symlink somewhere, but I think the accepted answer here may be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually

Comment: @jspinella There is a big difference. `alias` command is **temporary** and valid only for the session it has been issued in, and only for interactive commands (ie. in a script `python` won't be recognized as a command). `python-is-python3` installs an actual `/usr/bin/python` which is a symlink to `/usr/bin/python3`, so `python` becomes permanently equal to `python3` in virtually all contexts. So they are completely different.

Comment: So `alias` is temporary and `python-is-python3` installs a symlink to permanently point `python` to `python3`. `python-is-python3` does not install python3 and assumes python exists at `usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Awesome! Worked straight away, it is on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) container. Thank you @FabianoTarlao.

Comment: Useful for Ubuntu 22.04: Installed python3 and python-is-python3. Apparently new software should specify either python2 or python3, not python. This package adds a symlink to python3.

Comment: This worked for me on Zorin OS 16.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had same error

```
Ubuntu:/$ python

Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3       
sudo apt install python        
sudo apt install python-minimal

You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.
```

you can try

```
Ubuntu:/$ python2.7
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>>
```

this [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3) would help to make python alias.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that would work across different (and older) versions of Ubuntu is the "alternatives" system, either the command-line `update-alternatives` (should be installed) or GUI `galternatives` (not installed by default). It lets one configure your "preferred" version when you have multiple versions, or completely different but compatible implementations, (e.g. compilers, editors; see for example this dump: `update-alternatives --get-selections`).

To see which versions of python are currently the default (note: these are symbolic links to specific versions):

```
$ type python python2 python3
python not found
python2 is /usr/bin/python2
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
```

Usually (like, always, without exception) you want the default `python` to be `python2`, for compatibility reasons (otherwise **you will break** apt and other system utilities!) and then just explicitly invoke `python3` if and when you really mean Python3.

To see what current alternatives are configured for `python`:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --list python
error: no alternatives found
```

If alternatives *are* found, skip the following (see `--config`, below). Otherwise, we can configure both python2 and python3 as "alternatives" for the `python` command and you can switch between them (or just set `python2` here and you're done; the rest is here for completeness & as an exercise):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 40
using /usr/bin/python2 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode    

$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 20
using /usr/bin/python3 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode   

$ type python
/usr/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

*(Important! if your default python is showing as `python3`, then change it here to `python2`, otherwise `apt` and other system utilities may be broken!)*

To use `update-alternatives` to change the version currently selected, do the following and choose the version you want:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0          /usr/bin/python2     40         auto mode
  1          /usr/bin/python2     40         manual mode
  2          /usr/bin/python3     20         manual mode
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

To completely remove all `python` alternative configurations (e.g., to start over, or just undo everything if anything weird is going on):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
```

Comment: "you want the default python to be python2, for compatibility reasons" -- Thanks for pointing this out. I completely hosed a previous Ubuntu installation (<20.01) by trying to be forward-thinking in ditching python2 by aliasing python as python3, and never understood why everything stopped working. Now I see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Most times you've to use the keyword python3 to run the code other than just python on py, these won't work as expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1232714)