# python-is-python3 package in Ubuntu 20.04 - what is it and what does it actually do?

Tags: 20.04, python, python3

Having used Ubuntu 18.04 for a handful of years now, and reading that Python 2 has been removed from Ubuntu 20.04, I was looking forward to using the commands `python` or `pip` rather than `python3` or `pip3`.  So today I tried Ubuntu 20.04 for the first time, and found:

```
$ python --version

Command 'python' not found

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

I was surprised and upon looking into things further found the following about the package `python-is-python3`:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-is-python3

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/python-is-python3

[How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)

The middle of these 3 links is the most descriptive, but none are especially clear about what `python-is-python3` is/does and the full scope of ramifications if `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3` was to be ran on a Ubuntu 20.04 install.

Here are some questions I have about `python-is-python3`:

1. Is `python-is-python3` proprietary to Ubuntu/Canonical?  If so, do other Linux distributions use `python-is-python3` also or do some other distributions have a similar equivalent?
2. I gather if I was to run `python-is-python3` from the command prompt then I could use the command `python` instead of `python3`.  First can somebody confirm this, and second, does the same go for `pip`, i.e. `pip` instead of `pip3`?
3. The launchpad.net link above mentions creation of a symlink.  Does `python-is-python3` really just create a single symlink?  It seems odd to introduce a package for such a bare bones purpose.  Also, if this package is subsequently uninstalled (`i.e. sudo apt --purge remove python-is-python3`) does this remove the symlink?
4. Are there any commonly used Python 2 packages out there anymore?  I can't think of any offhand.
5. Has anybody ran `python-is-python3` and then later regretted doing so due to a reason that was not realized ahead of time?
6. It seems the benefit of running `python-is-python3` would be not having to add the 3 at the end of Python commands, but the disadvantage is that you would then have a non-standard Ubuntu setup, is this a fair summary of the `python-is-python3` benefit/drawback?

Comment: 1) [No](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/what-is-python). 2) Yes. No. 3) Yes. Yes. 4) No. 5) Impossible to know with certainty, since we don't allow rants or reviews here. 6) Yes.

Comment: "do some other distributions have a similar equivalent?" - RHEL8 did something similar, and broke everything that had a shebang of ```#!/usr/bin/env python```. Manjaro, which I use these days, seemed to handle the switch from Python 2 to 3 more smoothly.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As [the package description you linked to says](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/python-is-python3):

> In Ubuntu, all python packages use explicit python3 or python2 interpreter and do not use unversioned /usr/bin/python at all ... No packages may declare dependencies on this package.

So, all official Ubuntu packages will depend explicitly on "python2" or "python3", and invoke the appropriate command. The default "python" command is deliberately undefined so that any scripts referencing it have to be updated to unambiguously depend on one version or the other.

However, *users* may have code that relies on the "python" command being available, and know that they can safely point it *across their whole system* to one version or the other. The `python-is-python3` package (and [its counterpart, `python-is-python2`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/python-is-python2)) are a convenient way to set up a symlink for this purpose.

> Does python-is-python3 really just create a single symlink? It seems odd to introduce a package for such a bare bones purpose.

Linux distributions are extremely complex systems made up of a large number of simple components. The power of package managers comes in their flexibility to do simple things like this in a unified way. For instance, a server setup script might have a long list of `apt` packages that an application needs to be installed, and can simply include `python-is-python3` in that list. Shipping a package for this purpose is *considerably simpler* than having a user guide explaining how to manage the symlink manually.

> Does the same go for `pip`, i.e. `pip` instead of `pip3`?

Apparently not - according to [this LaunchPad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/what-is-python/+bug/1887098), the `python3` package automatically points `pip` at `pip3` anyway.

If you open up the `.deb` file for the package (I used 7-Zip), you can see that apart from some documentation, it really does just contain one symlink, to be installed at `/usr/bin/python`, pointing to `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: As for `pip` - to avoid surprises (think: many Python versions in the system, plus conda envs, plus virtualenvs...), it is often a good idea to run it as `[/path/to/]python -m pip ...`

Answer (score 25):

In Ubuntu, all python packages use explicit python3 or python2 interpreter and do not use unversioned `/usr/bin/python` at all. Some third-party code is now predominantly python3 based, yet may use `/usr/bin/python`.

python-is-python3 is a convenience package which ships a symlink to point the `/usr/bin/python` interpreter at the current default python3. It may improve compatibility with other modern systems, while breaking some obsolete or third-party software.

python-is-python3 replaces: python, python-is-python2.

I installed python-is-python3 as a convenience package in Ubuntu 20.04, but I later uninstalled it after python2.7 was automatically installed as a dependency of another package.

Comment: See my https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295530/python-and-virtualbox-vs-virtualbox-6-1, and it'll explain why python-is-python2 got installed.

Comment: I think the url of your references is needed.

Comment: The reference I used is the output of `apt show python-is-python3`