# The appearance of various programs has changed to look old-fashioned

Tags: gnome-shell, appearance

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

A member of the openshot team was helping me fix a problem and suddenly all the graphics went to Windows 3.1 He helped me to reinstall gnome but some issues haven't been fixed. Also, quite a few programs disappeared and I had to download them.

As seen below, the terminal appears 'old.' Before it was beautiful and purple. There was a hamburger menu in the right corner. Various icons now also look old fashioned, but some things are back to normal. Sorry that I don't have more info, I was just following his suggestions blindly and don't recall what happened exactly.

[image: screenshot]

Output of `history`

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openshot
  460  sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove openshot  
  461  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ffmpeg
  462  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge openshot
  463  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge openshot-qt
  464  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
  465  sudo apt-get update
  466  sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
  467  openshot-qt --debug
  468  sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
  469  sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg:i386
  470  dpkg-query -l ffmpeg
  471  dpkg-query -l python3
  472  sudo apt update
  473  sudo apt upgrade
  474  sudo apt autoremove
  475  sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
  476  dpkg- query - l - ffmpeg
  477  dpkg-query -l ffmpeg
  478  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py
  479  python /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py
  480  sudo apt-get sudo apt-cache policy
  481  sudo apt-cache policy
  482  sudo apt-cache policy | grep openshot
  483  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:openshot.developers/libopenshot-daily
  484  add-apt-repository command not found
  485  which add-apt-repository
  486  sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
  487  sudo apt-get reinstall openshot-qt
  488  sudo dpkg-query -l software-properties-common
  489  sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
  490  dpkg-query: no packages found matching software-properties-common
  491  whik dpkg-query
  492  which dpkg-query
  493  /usr/bin/dpkg-query -l software-properties-common
  494  openshot-qt --debug
  495  sudo pip install PyQt5
  496  sudo pip3 install PyQt5
  497  sudo pip3 install pyqt5
  498  sudo apt-get purge python3
  499  sudo apt-get install python3
  500  sudo dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep python
  501  sudo apt-get remove python-is-python2
  502  sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
  503  sudo dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep python
  504  sudo pip3 --version
  505  sudo apt-get install python3-pip
  506  sudo pip3 --version
  507  sudo apt-get python3-pyqt5
  508  sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
  509  sudo pip3 install PyQt5
  510  cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
  511  ls -al libopenshot.so.19
  512  clear
  513  openshot-qt --debug
  514  dpkg-query -l openshot-qt
  515  sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
  516  openshot-qt --debug
  517  clear
  518  sudo dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep python
  519  python /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py
  520  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py
  521  python bash: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py: Permission deniedpy
  522  python /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py
  523  cd
  524  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.pysudo apt-get purge openshot-qt
  525  sudo apt-get purge openshot-qt
  526  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
  527  sudo add-apt-repository -r
  528  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
  529  i pressed enter to continue and it instantly went to a blank line
  530  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
  531  cd
  532  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
  533  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:openshot.developers/libopenshot-daily
  534  sudo apt-cache policy | grep openshot
  535  python!
  536  cd
  537  sudo apt-cache policy | grep openshot
  538  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/libopenshot-daily
  539  sudo apt-get update
  540  sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
  541  openshot-qt
  542  sudo apt-get install synaptic
  543  synaptic &
  544  sudo synaptic &
  545  sudo apt-get install firefox
  546  firefoz
  547  firefox
  548  openshot-qt --debug
  549  openshot-qtqt
  550  openshot-qt --debug

  554  sudo dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep ffmpeg
  555  ffmpeg -version
  556  ls -al /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/__init__.py
  557  ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*openshot*
  558  sudo apt-get update
  559  sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Have you gone through the application settings?  What are the options under "view"?

Comment: From looking at the history, I suspect the problem is that you messed around with python, a critical system package. Fixing the result is beyond me.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for that. Nothing under view or in the preference appearance settings fixed this

Comment: There's this `sudo apt-get remove python-is-python2 /  sudo apt-get install python-is-python3` I don't have those packages on my 18.04 install but it sounds like it changed the system python version.  See https://askubuntu.com/q/1296790/243321

Comment: @OrganicMarble none of the standard apps use the symlink `python`, most likely the `python3` symlink changed.

Comment: @RayWu
 'python-is-python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-4)' But I notice that in my About section it says Gnome version is 3.36.3

Comment: @CatoCross Are you sure that terminal is gnome-terminal? Type `xprop` and click on the terminal and show the results.

Comment: @RayWu  Thanks!  https://docs.google.com/document/d/16CYdIm4HqxJSTozMbgm1Z5tbQ8ZOZVmvq7gV-_qI6vA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RayWu Terminal and about sections show different versions of Gnome installed. 3.36.3 and the other says 3.36.4 . Not sure if relevant.

Comment: @CatoCross AHA! This is *not* gnome-terminal, it's qterminal. Try typing alt-f2 and typing `gnome-terminal`

Comment: @RayWu  Posted the solution above. Seems i have different DE installed. Do you think I should do a fresh install of ubuntu?

Comment: @CatoCross No, there is no need to do that. Just try uninstalling the package `kubuntu-desktop` and running `sudo apt autoremove`. And you are welcome to write that as an answer directly if you want, it's encouraged to help others with a similar problem.

Comment: @RayWu Thanks! When i boot up, in the gear icon for the login screen  I have many options: LXqt / Ubuntu wayland / Gnome / Gnome desktop. Should i remove the others ones too?

Comment: @CatoCross Please remove the solution from your question, it clutters the text and is unnecessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117032/discussion-between-ray-wu-and-cato-cross).

Comment: @RayWu  Removed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The terminal is not GNOME Terminal at all. It looks like the terminal from the LXQt desktop environment.

```
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
sudo apt remove qterminal
```

I also see Discover, which is the app store from the KDE Plasma desktop environment. It looks like you mixed a bunch of DEs, which is not recommended, and you may want to remove it with

```
sudo apt remove plasma-discover
```

I think you likely also reinstalled the normal GNOME Software app, instead of the variation of it that Canonical created to support snaps.

```
sudo apt remove gnome-software
sudo snap install snap-store
```

You can also try these commands:

```
sudo apt remove kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
```