# How to run scripts using python instead of python3?

Tags: 20.04, python

```
which python
/home/tanvir/.pyenv/shims/python
```

```
which python3
/home/tanvir/.pyenv/shims/python3
```

I want `python` to point `/home/tanvir/.pyenv/shims/python3` so that once I run `python path/to/script` it runs `python3 path/to/script`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python-is-python3 package in Ubuntu 20.04 - what is it and what does it actually do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually)

Comment: It is a matter for you to learn working with pyenv, which has its own mechanisms to set your default python versio. I changed my answer to provide instructions specific for pyenv.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you do not do this. Pythons 2 and 3 have some incompatibilities and for a long time the convention was for hashbangs at the top of Python scripts to select 2 with `#!/usr/bin/env python` and 3 with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. The former convention is starting to vanish, but you may still come across old scripts that are specifically trying to select Python 2 with `#!/usr/bin/env python` and your configuration of having `python` run Python 3 will break them.

Comment: There is no reason why you could not have python point to python3 instead of python2. Ubuntu even provides a package that implements a symbolic link for python to version 2 or 3. Of course indeed, Python 2 scripts break on python 3.

Comment: @vanadium There is nothing in the operating system stopping you from linking anything to anything else you like, correct. That has nothing to do with my answer, which is not about _can_ you do this but _should_ you do this.

Comment: There was a time *(pre version 3)* when **python** was just that … regardless of the version number and no one thought about it twice … then came **python3** [the first ever intentionally backwards incompatible Python release](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) and now people argue whether **python** is **python2** or **python3** … I wonder what will python4 bring with it :)

Comment: The upstream Python Project answer: [PEP 394](https://peps.python.org/pep-0394/)

Comment: @user535733 in your link I see what I wrote above: python can be python2 or python3. Or do I miss something? User wants to make python = python3. This question is not related to the shebang, where the recommendation is to be specific.

Comment: @cjs To me, there is nothing in the current question that is not in agreement with the  recommendation of the Python Project, linked to by user535733 in the comment above.

Comment: @vanadium True, as long as the user understands the consequences and is willing to be responsible for fixing any breakage. However, users seeking an easy answer without willingness to encounter consequences would be wise to heed this answer. Both answers are good.

Comment: @vanadium PEP 394's suggestion that "...publishers can expect users of the software to provide a suitable execution environment" seems faintly ridiculous to me. Does the OP appear to you to be qualified to do this?

Comment: I am not judging the skills of the OP. The question is fully conforming to the recommendation of PEP 394, and thus deserves, in my opinion, an objective answer on how to have python point to python3.

Comment: @vanadium I am glad you agree with me that the question deserves an objective answer on how to have `python` point to `python3`. I am not clear on what the point is of your comments on this answer, though. Do you think that this answer is somehow preventing other answers from being posted that explain how to change the link?

Comment: My objections 1) it is fully acceptable to have python point to python 3, so there is no objective reason to discourage this - it even goes against the PEP recommendations. Of course, indicate possible caveats along with an answer is fine. I also do not think your information with respect to the shebang is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Although you did not explicitly tell, you have set up and are using `pyenv`. This is a tool written in `bash` that allows to manage different python version on a per user basis.

To change your default python version, you need to use the tool. Currently, your python version may still be set to the python version installed with the Ubuntu system.

1. List the available python versions with the command

   ```
   pyenv versions
   ```
2. Then change the default python version with a command like

   ```
   pyenv global 3.6.8
   ```

   Adapt `3.6.8` according to the output you found in step one.

Besides setting the global default python version for you user, you can set different default python version for different projects. Inform yourself to learn more about the tool `pyenv`.

- Beware that `which python` will continue to point to `/home/tanvir/.pyenv/shims/python`. This is because of the way `pyenv` works. That executable is a "shims", a short bash script that converts your `python` command to a call to the configured default python version.
- If step 1 does not reveal any python version apart from `system`, you will need to install some python  versions using `pyenv`.

For users not using `pyenv`, Ubuntu provides packages to install a symbolic link that points to the desired python version, i.e., `python-is-python2` and `python-is-python3`. On the latest Ubuntu versions, `python2` is not installed by default, and only the latter package is available.

Comment: I renamed the python executable and created a symbolic link to python3 named python then checked versions for both ```python``` and ```python3``` but the versions were different. Then I removed the symbolic link and copied ```python3``` executable and named ```python``` still the versions are different

Comment: Then you are copying/linking different executables than these that show up with `which`, or something else is going on we cannot see from here.

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though you are using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) which is designed for the purpose of selecting which python version to use. The documentation on that page has instructions for changing your selection. One way is to run : `$ pyenv global 3.9.0` (change as appropriate for the python versions you have installed. `pyenv versions` will show you)

Neither `/home/tanvir/.pyenv/shims/python` nor `/home/tanvir/.pyenv/shims/python3` are real python executables, but are shims that pass through to one of the installed python versions depending on the pyenv setting.

It's not clear what context you want to use python3 as a default in:

- Globally for you as a user
- In a single shell session
- Globally for all users
- For a single project

There are different ways and tools for each of these, e.g. if it's a single project, then [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) ([pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv)) may be the best tool. For a single shell session running `$ alias python=python3` may be the best option.

Comment: This is the first anwer pointing to the correct approach for this specific question, i.e. using the pyenv tools to configure which python version you want to run through the command `python`. Please explain a bit about shim and provide more concise instructions on how to have `python` run `python3`. The `alias` option very likely has little relevance - I suggest to delete that.

Answer (score 1):

There's another approach that is starting to gain some traction, which is to use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (or equivalent with python2). By using this variation, it will pick up whichever matching version of python is in your path first, but this allows you to have different virtual environments without hard-coding the path to the system-installed python.

Then you can just run `path/to/script` and it will load the expected version of python for you without having to specify it on the command line.

Comment: The shebang -only- plays a role if the script is executable -and- run without explicitly calling the interpreter in the command. If the script is not executable, the command will fail, despite your shebang, when calling the interpreter in the command, you might as well have "#!/monkey/eats/banana" as a shebang, it'll still work, from the interpreter that is called in the command (if the script is valid for that python version).

Comment: Question indeed here is to execute `python`, and have that be `python3`.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned this only applies when you treat the script as executable. The @cjs answer is more detailed and better than mine; as to whether or not they're on-topic for the OP the question seems likely to come up as a hit when people are searching for ways to run the right version of python from a script, so hopefully the content will help someone.