# "/tmp/geany_run_script_SO5U41.sh: 7: python: not found" - F5 key doesn't execute script in geany

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, geany

I'm using Geany for the first time. I'm trying to run the sample script I've written (please see screenshot 1) by pressing F5 - normally, this should open the terminal and execute the code.

(According to the [documentation](https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/sorted_keyboard_shortcuts), F5 'executes the current file in a terminal emulation'.)

However, I get the error:

```
/tmp/geany_run_script_SO5U4.sh: 7: python: not found

------------------
(program exited with code: 127)

Press return to continue
```

The text of the script was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 3

print('Python is awesome!')
```

The code works fine when executed directly from the terminal:

```
python3 sample_script.py
```

which outputs `Python is awesome!` as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question.

Comment: Recent versions of Ubuntu require python to be invoked explicitly as either `python2` or `python3` - so you may need to go into the geany build commands menu and modify the "Execute" command from `python "%f"` to `python3 "%f"`. See also [python-is-python3 package in Ubuntu 20.04 - what is it and what does it actually do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually)

Comment: @steeldriver I did exactly as you said and it now works, thank you!