# how to make python3 the default python? system wide not for a specific user

Tags: python, python3

with python 2 reaching EOL how to make python3 the default python ? ...  system wide not just a specific script

should we do a symbolic link ?

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

or possibly

```
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3
```

Does it matter which ?  I am on a box without python 2 so I have no python 2 specific libraries to deal with.

of course just making below edit to your ~/.bashrc will only impact one user

```
alias python=python3
```

I am looking for a system wide change for all processes and userids not just  me

Comment: [PEP394](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) says "Don't do that!" See previous thread on the topic: [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)

Comment: @user535733  that answer is only good for one user it does no system wide change

Comment: Read a bit farther down that duplicate - both of your proposed methods are addressed.