# eye of gnome, randomize slideshow plugin not working (pluginloader python3 not found)

Tags: python3, plugins, eog

Well as per title, I tried to use the randomize plugin for slideshows for eye of gnome

https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/plugins.html.en

```
apt-get install eog-plugins
```

However when I now try to active the plugin it doesn't work and a hover test with "plugin loader python3 not found"

However whenever I go to a shell and I type `python3 --version` (or `python --version`) I get `Python 3.8.10` - so python is working.

How can one make this work?

Comment: This answer should help you https://askubuntu.com/a/321000/917609

Comment: @Serg to put it direct that answer didn't do anything. All aliases are towards python 3 already, even the python 3 alias

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Serg yes - and as I've already shown I already have `python` aliased to `python3`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry missed this.