# Installing then immediately uninstalling "python" breaks Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop

Tags: 23.04

I completely broke my 2-month-old 23.04 installation today.

Steps:

1. Needed python for something so `python` -> `Command 'python' not found...`
2. Installed python `sudo apt install python`
3. Noticed it installed python 2.7 instead of python3 `sudo apt remove python`

Then the system crashed, flashed on the screen of the fs being corrupted and completely failed to post for ~30 minutes.

Now my Ubuntu boots into a terminal, no desktop, no networking, usb works though.

I'm not sure how any of this is even possible because:

- `python` has no installation candidate on any of my other systems (all fresh installs), I'm not sure how it installed in the first place
- should uninstalling freshly installed python affect Ubuntu desktop, especially since `/usr/bin/python` is no longer installed by default
- `python3.11.4` is still installed on the system which is the default

Could I be looking at a hardware issue or might this be an Ubuntu thing?

Everything works fine on a live Ubuntu boot image.

Comment: `python3` runs python 3; where `python` runs the earlier python2 as the Python specs still default to (*written long ago & unchanged*). You should **not** remove the default python3 on a Ubuntu Desktop system; did you want `python2` or just want to use the already installed `python3` system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)

Comment: In regards to "how is this possible" - You destroyed your system by messing about with Python. Your first error was thinking it wasn't installed (it is a key component of Ubuntu) then your second was trying to fix this.

Comment: If you run `sudo apt uninstall python` on a fresh 23.04, it says it cannot find python. I know the difference python and python3. The point is, Ubuntu no longer supports installing Python2.7 as `apt install python`. Maybe you didn't read my whole question. Python3 is still on my system, didn't touch it. The base `python` (2.7 presumably) was never in any of my `*/bin` directories until I installed it, then immediately uninstalled it. Even weirder, `python` has no installation candidate. Just very strange all around.